# GeoServer feature type loading issue

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver

I have a table on a PostGIS database with these fields:

- id [serial integer]
- pname [text]
- links [text]
- area [integer]
- docs [json]

For this layer, I have created a WFS layer on GeoServer.
However, the feature type loaded by GeoServer consists only of the fields

- id [serial integer]
- links [text]
- area [integer]
- docs [json]

that is, the `pname` field is missing.
Reloading the feature type, I do not get any error notification.
However, I get an error when I want to write to the WFS layer from QGIS.

```
Provider errors:
      WFS service exception: 
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for fid: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 35: mylayer.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse
    Parsing failed for fid: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 35: mylayer.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse
    Illegal character in path at index 35: mylayer.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse.Schöneberger Linse
```

My assumption is, that Geoserver is ommiting the field, because of Umlaute in the values for this field. (The other text field `links` that does not contain Umlaute, gets loaded)

I have checked the global GeoServer settings, that the `Service Response Settings` -> `Character set` is "UTF-8".
Also for the database, `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;` is "UTF8".

Any idea, why GeoServer would be ommitting this field from the Feature Type?

Comment: Name is a reserved name in gml along with id. Your error is caused by the space in your layer name.

Comment: Thanks, @IanTurton. The layer name 'mylayer' in GeoServer and the table name 'mylayer' in PostGIS do not contain spaces. Only the object's value for 'name' contains a space.

Comment: @IanTurton The value 'name' was an alias I added here for the real field's name, I have adjusted this.

Comment: I assume that this issue is related to a database view which is referencing the entry from the table 'mylayer' and potentially get's updated when writing to the WFS layer.

Comment: Can you look in the GeoServer log file and find the actual error message from there - that should give us more information, but it looks like GeoServer can't parse the FID as a URI but I'm not sure why it is trying to do that.

Comment: Sounds to me that Geoserver assumes that the "pname" column is primary key and thus treated as FID. Read out some features and examine what FID it has. Also if Id column is present it is not the actual FID (unless you checked "expose primary keys")